# Uneven rep in R

Tags: r

I have a question on how to unevenly repeat number with each and times. I have the following code and have a hard time formatting it. For this example, I hope to repeat the number "1" for 10 times then "2" for 2 time, then repeat for 10 cycles

```
df <- rep(c("1","2"), each = c(10,2), times = 10)
```

in the end, it would be

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2.....
```

or 
10 cycles of

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
```

Thank you!

Comment: `rep(c(rep("1", 10), rep("2", 2)), 10)`

Comment: perfect - thank you!

Comment: Also `rep(rep(1:2, c(10, 2)), times = 10)`, maybe generalizes a little more easily.